# Matlab: Using a Java Class without Matlab Compiler Runtime

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-compiler

If I create a Java class with Matlab Compiler SDK, I understand that I need a Matlab installation or Matlab Runtime for building the whole Java application where the class is integrated into on the developers machine.
But must an end user, who will use the application on a completely different system, have an installation of the Matlab Runtime?

Comment: I don't have experience with that particular application, but I believe that anything built with compiler sdk requires the runtime [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/) suggests that all products require the supporting runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the end user will need a copy of the MATLAB Runtime.